# PyQGIS - QgsPalLayerSettings - Vector Labels Scale Visibility

Tags: labeling, pyqgis-3

I've created a script to automate loading layers from different sources.
This includes dxf files that have a LineString layer and a Point Layer.
For the dxf files I want to turn off the symbols for the point layer and display labels from the "Text" field.

The only part I can't get to work is applying the scale visibility. I found this solution - [Restrict when point labels are displayed using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372923/restrict-when-point-labels-are-displayed-using-pyqgis), but it doesn't work for me. Running my script does not raise any errors.

Below is my code where I'm extracting the point layer from the DXF, set the symbols to size zero, and then setting up the labels:

```
    labelsLayerName = "LotLabels"

    #retrieve dxf point layer
    dxfPointLayer = dxf[0] + "|layername=entities|geometrytype=Point"
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(dxfPointLayer, labelsLayerName, "ogr")

    #remove symbols
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(vlayer.geometryType())
    symbol.setSize(0)
    rendererr = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol)
    vlayer.setCustomProperty
    vlayer.setRenderer(rendererr)

    #set labels
    palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    palyr.fieldName = "Text"
    palyr.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint
    palyr.ScaleVisibility = True
    palyr.minimumScale = 750
    labels = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(palyr)
    vlayer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    vlayer.setLabeling(labels)
    vlayer.triggerRepaint()
    
    #add layer to project
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Comment: I think it's `palyr.scaleVisibility = True` and not `palyr.ScaleVisibility = True`

Comment: Now I feel stupid! Thanks @JULESG